# rewrite rule base on first sub domain to directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need to redirect the first sub domain of any domain name that will hit the root folder of that web server to a subfolder.

- It need to keep the incoming port (stupid isp that block port 80 and 443).
- It need to be able to handle both http and https.
- It need to ignore www.whateverthedomain.ext

Ex.

- dom1 : mydummy.com
- dom2 : toberedirected.net
- dom3 : putanydomainhere.ca

possible incoming url

1. http(s)://firstsub.mydummy.com:8082
2. http(s)://whateveryoutypehere.thegoodsub.toberedirected.net
3. http(s)://firstsub.mydummy.com/firstsub/
4. http(s)://www.mydummy.com/

The result of the 3 incoming url should be

1. http(s)://firstsub.mydummy.com:8082/firstsub/
2. http(s)://thegoodsub.toberedirected.net/thegoodsub/ (i dont care what is in front of the first sub)
3. http(s)://firstsub.mydummy.com/firstsub/ (dont rewrite, it is not the root folder)
4. http(s)://www.mydummy.com/ (dont rewrite, ignore www and give default webpage of the domain)

It is probably easy to write but i cannot figure it out this morning.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.
RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1/ [L,R=301]
```

This should preserve the hostname and port when redirecting. It will only redirect requests for the web root, and will redirect to the name of the subdomain, with a trailing `/`.